# Why is my RadioGroup returning 'false'

Tags: java, android, dialog, radio-button

I have a custom Dialog with a RadioGroup containing two RadioButtons. The RadioButton selected determines the String that is to be set. When I do

```
 Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
```

It shows checkedId as being false regardless of which RadioButton is selected and only the second case sets the String to the correct value. Below is my code currently:

```
AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewFile.this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.jquery_dialog, null);
        final EditText idTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idName);
        final CheckBox headerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.headerChk);
        final CheckBox footerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.footerChk);
        final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) view
                .findViewById(R.id.jqmNavigation);
        customDialog.setView(idTxt);
        customDialog.setView(headerChk);
        customDialog.setView(footerChk);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.ol: // First RadioButton
                    Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    jqMobNavbar = "<div data-role=\"navbar\">\n" + "        <ol>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 1</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 2</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 3</a></li>\n"
                            + "     <ol>\n" + " </div>\n";
                    break;
                case R.id.ul: // Second RadioButton
                    Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    jqMobNavbar = "<div data-role=\"navbar\">\n" + "        <ul>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 1</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 2</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 3</a></li>\n"
                            + "     <ul>\n" + " </div>\n";
                    break;

                }

            }
        });
```

and my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.androidwebtoolkit.TransparentPanel
        android:id="@+id/transparentPanel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="jBuilder"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jquerymobileicon" />

    </com.androidwebtoolkit.TransparentPanel>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="ID:"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/idName"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/headerChk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Header" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/footerChk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Footer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Navigation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/jqmNavigation"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ordered List" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unordered List" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've also tried

```
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int idx = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                switch (idx) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    jqMobNavbar = "<div data-role=\"navbar\">\n" + "        <ol>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 1</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 2</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 3</a></li>\n"
                            + "     <ol>\n" + " </div>\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    jqMobNavbar = "<div data-role=\"navbar\">\n" + "        <ul>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 1</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 2</a></li>\n"
                            + "         <li><a href=\"#\">Page 3</a></li>\n"
                            + "     <ul>\n" + " </div>\n";
                    break;

                }

            }
        });
```

What is the correct way to check the value of the RadioButton selected?

Comment: What do you mean by "It shows checkedId as being false" ?
checkedId is an int, and (in your case) it should be either R.id.ol or R.id.ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean checkedId is false? It's an int and cannot be false. If either of your case statements works, that means checkedId is the id value it's supposed to be.

If you set the first RadioButton as checked in XML, neither of your cases will be called until the other button is pressed. Alternatively, you can also set a: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html 
on each button.

Comment: By 'false' I mean the result for Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show(); is a toast showing 'false'

Comment: I think it was an Eclipse problem. A reboot and project clean got it working using the switch(checkedId) I tried first

Comment: Glad you got it working. Good 'ol Eclipse. I can't tell you how many issues I've solved with a clean/restart.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `false` becouse its an `Integer`. try to use:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(checkedId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```